# Windows script to return matching dir name to variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

everyone
I want to write a Windows script to grep and return the python directory name from `C:\` to a variable. It might be more than one matching. May I know how can I achieve that?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry... I am reffering to command line in Window.

Comment: Try `echo %PYTHONPATH%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set $c=1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b c:\ ^| find /i "python"') do (
  set "##!$c!=%%a"
  set /a $c+=1
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set ##') do echo Found --^> %%a
```

This will create variable(s) ##1 to ##x containing all the directory in `c:\` containing the word `python`

Answer (score 0):

Build a [PATH-like variable](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) `_python`:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "_python="
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('where /R c:\ python') do (
  set "_python=!_python!;%%~dpG"
  echo %%~nxG found in "%%~dpG" 
)
rem remove leading ;
if defined _python set "_python=%_python:~1%"
echo(
echo %_python%
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- `%%~nxG` [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- `%_python:~1%` [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)